# Move or copy folders into other folders based on a unique identifier

Tags: python

I have two directories: Payslips and Users.
**Payslips** contains 142 folders named as follows: **yymm_employeeNumber_Employee Name**
**Users** contains 142 folders named as follows: **employeeNumber_Employee Name**

I'd like to copy each folder from payslips to the corresponding folder in users based on employeeNumber.

So far I am trying unsuccessfully to test matching the folders based on employeeNumber at #3.

If you would please first point out what's wrong with my code at #3.
Then if you could help me solve the hole problem correctly I would be very thankful!

```
import os

# 1.Read user folders into list: users and payslip folders into list: payslips
users = os.listdir("/path/to/directoty")
payslips = os.listdir("/path/to/directory")


# 2. Split each element in both lists
for user in users:
    user = user.split("_")

for payslip in payslips:
    payslip = payslip.split("_")


# 3. Match EmployeeNumbers of payslips with those of users
for payslip in payslips:
    # Ignore this hidden file (on my Mac)
    if payslip == ['.DS', 'Store']:
        continue
    if payslip[1] == user[0]:
        print(f"{payslip} belongs to {user}")
    else:
        print("No match found")
```

Output

```
No match found
No match found
No match found
No match found
No match found
No match found
No match found
....
```

Many thanks!

Comment: your step 2 does not seem to be correct. first create an empty list and split the names in to this list. use `print` statement for checking out the resulting output before moving on to the next step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to traverse all the users folder and find matching `payslip` folder.

I have created a similar scenario with the following folder structure:

```
├── copy_data.py
├── data
│   ├── Payslips
│   │   ├── 2201_6_arsho
│   │   └── 2205_5_Shovon
│   └── Users
│       ├── 5_Shovon
│       └── 6_arsho
```

copy_data.py:

```
import os

users = os.listdir("data/Users")
payslips = os.listdir("data/Payslips")

# 2. Split each element in both lists
for user in users:
    if "_" not in user:
        continue
    user_employee_number = user.split("_")[0]
    
    # 3. Match EmployeeNumbers of payslips with those of users
    for payslip in payslips:
        # Ignore this hidden file (on my Mac)
        if payslip == ['.DS', 'Store']:
            continue
        if payslip.split("_")[1] == user_employee_number:
            print(f"{payslip} belongs to {user}")
```

**Output:**

```
2205_5_Shovon belongs to 5_Shovon
2201_6_arsho belongs to 6_arsho
```

For the copy purpose, try using [`shutil` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html).

Comment: Glad to hear that. It if solves the problem, mark it as accepted.

Comment: Any Idea how I'm supposed to use the shutil to copy the files :) ??

Comment: You can try using `shutil.copytree` method.